# attributes of an automatically created objects

Tags: android, oop, object, arraylist

i have an arraylisy which is filled by movie objects

a "movie" object is created on every click of a certain button
and given its attributes from data given by the user

the problem is on every creation of an object , names of all objects are changed to the name of the last one created
what is the problem of my code

```
public class MovieReg_activity extends Activity {

    public static List<movie> movies = new ArrayList<movie>();

    String movName ;
    int dvdNo ;
    int x=0 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mov_reg_layout);
        EditText etdvd_no = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdvds);
        Button btMovie_submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btmovsubmit);


    //  dvdNo = Integer.parseInt(etdvd_no.getText().toString()); // to string then to int :)

        btMovie_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText etmovie_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmovname);

                movName= etmovie_name.getText().toString();
                movies.add(x,new movie(movName , dvdNo) );
                String name3= movie.getName() ;
                x++ ;
                int size =movies.size() ;
                Toast.makeText(MovieReg_activity.this, "no of movies added :"+size , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

            }
        });

    }

}
```

class movie

```
public class movie {

    public static  String name45;
    int dvd_no ;

    public  movie( String name1 , int dvd_no1) 
    {
        this.name45=name1 ;
            this.dvd_no = dvd_no1 ; 

                Log.d("DEBUG", "constructor name1 " + name1);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "constructor name45 " + name45);

    }

    public static String getName()
    {
        return name45 ;
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, this code doesn't look like it will compile with the line "String name3= movie.getName();" There is no movie object defined, unless getName() is a static method?

Comment: @KarimVarela edited and added class movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your movie class, name45 is set as a static variable. That means that there's only one copy of that variable for all movie objects. Make getName() not static and make name45 not static. That should fix your problem.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText etmovie_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmovname);

    movName= etmovie_name.getText().toString();
    movie movieToAdd = new movie(movName, dvdNo);
    movies.add(x,movieToAdd );
    String name3= movieToAdd.getName() ;
    x++ ;
    int size =movies.size() ;
    Toast.makeText(MovieReg_activity.this, "no of movies added :"+size , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

}
```

Comment: gives me an error at every time i call  getName() !!

Comment: You need to call getName() from an instance of the movie object, added code.